# sense of $\exp(x^\top A x) = \exp(A x x^\top)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I wonder how the following identity makes sense?

$\exp(x^\top A x) = \exp(A x x^\top)$

My approach:

$\exp(x^\top A x) = \exp(\operatorname{tr}(x^\top A x)) = \exp(\operatorname{tr}(Axx^\top)) = \det(\exp(Axx^\top))$

But what should it formally mean to drop the determinant? This is used [here](http://www.genome.duke.edu/labs/engelhardt/courses/scribe/lec_09_09_2013.pdf) to identify an exponential form; but there is no determinant..

Comment: This doesn't make sense, provided that $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix and $x$ is an $n \times 1$ vector anyway. The LHS is a number but the RHS is a matrix.

Comment: Your cycling of the trace doesn't make sense to me, since $x$ is a vector not a matrix. Given that, and the other issues raised by Travis and daw, can you give a source for this proble,?

Comment: http://www.genome.duke.edu/labs/engelhardt/courses/scribe/lec_09_09_2013.pdf
bottom page 3 and following

Comment: @daw I agree that this must not be true in general. With the determinant $\det(\exp(...))$ as in my post it is the trace identity though.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, also the cycling inside the trace is ok.

Comment: Where is the identity $\exp(x^\top A x) = \exp(A x x^\top)$
in the notes you link to?

Comment: @Did Eq(9) is said to be in exponential form with the given sufficient statistic and natural parameters. Multiplying those does not yield the trace...doesn't this imply implicitly that identity? How else should this work?

Comment: Sorry but I see no identity similar to $\exp(x^\top A x) = \exp(A x x^\top)$ in Equation (9).

Comment: @Did Eq (9) has $tr(Axx^t)$ in the exponent which is said to be in exponential form as shown in Eq (10), whereas this term then would after multiplying the given sufficient statistic and parameters look like $Axx^t$ and not $tr(Axx^t)$ (or $tr(x^tAx)$). Hence we would need $\exp(x^tAx) = \exp(tr(x^tAx)) = \exp(tr(Axx^t)) = \exp(Axx^t)$, no?

Comment: Yes, Eq (9) mentions $\mathrm{tr}(Axx^T)$, not $Axx^T$. Hence, in the string of identities $\exp(x^tAx)=\exp(\mathrm{tr}(x^tAx))=\exp(\mathrm{tr}(Axx^t))=\exp(Axx^t)$, the three first quantities are well defined and coincide but the last one is absurd and not mentioned in the link.

Comment: I agree that the last makes no sense, that's why I was asking. I guess then my mistake lies somewhere else, as I don't see how Eq (10) should be equal to Eq(9) then after plugging in the given $T(x)$ and $\bar\eta$?

Comment: @Did I think the same thing which confuses me happens another time when they give the log-partition function $\frac{1}{2}\eta^tA\eta = \frac{1}{2}A\eta\eta^t$ one line further down.

Comment: The identity $\frac12\eta^T\Lambda\eta=\frac12\Lambda\eta\eta^T$ is absurd (the LHS is a number while the RHS an $n\times n$ matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
\det\exp(Axx^T)
$$
is the product of the eigenvalues of this matrix (assuming complex $A$). However, the rank of matrix $Axx^T$ is one (and zero if $x=0$). So the determinant is just $e^\lambda$ with $\lambda$ being the only nonzero eigenvalue of $Axx^T$. Its eigenvector is $Ax$ (assuming $Ax\ne0$):
$$
(Axx^T)Ax= (x^TAx)Ax,
$$
hence $\lambda = x^TAx$,
and
$$
\det\exp(Axx^T) = \exp(x^TAx).
$$

Comment: Cool!
Why is it ok to permute $Axx^t$ in the second equation?
And do you have an idea about my original question why they can leave out the determinant in the linked pdf and in what sense that makes sense?

Comment: $x^TAx$ is a number thus commutes with everything else.